# The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

How do I fix this error?

```
The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables.
```

My proc is:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetJobInfo]
    (
    @jobId int,
    @subject varchar(50) OUTPUT,
    @Body ntext OUTPUT,
    @prepared_email_id int OUTPUT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT TOP 1 @prepared_email_id = p.[PreparedEmailID],
        @subject = p.[Subject],
        @Body = p.[Body]
        FROM [PreparedEmails] p INNER JOIN
        [Jobs] j ON p.[PreparedEmailID] =
        j.[PreparedEmailID]
        WHERE j.[JobID] = @jobId
    RETURN
END
```

I don't know what the error is or how I fix it.
Please help me...

Comment: [ntext, text, and image](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(v=sql.90).aspx): "ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's telling you that you are not allowed to use NTEXT as a data type for local variables.

Changing `@Body ntext OUTPUT` to `@Body NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT` will get it working.

Comment: and for image use varbinary(max)

Comment: Why does this limitation exist? String literal of type `text` seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to want to extract out to a local variable

Comment: @Alexander why is Microsoft Microsoft? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old but worth mentioning. If your tables require those data types, cast your variables when you do the select or update/insert...

```
SELECT cast(@somevariable as ntext) from...

Update some table set somevalue=cast(@somevariable as ntext) where...
```